# How to return a lambda function and use by passing as an argument to a method in Java 8? Why I can't use :: operator?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I have tried to implement custom validation predicates in my Role class. i.e `isInRealm()` which returns a `Predicate<String>` and is a basic one only to show my intent.

```
public enum Role {
    USER("ROLE_user", 1),
    CUSTOMER("ROLE_customer", 2),
//...
    public static Predicate<String> isInRealm() {
         return role -> Arrays.stream(values()).anyMatch(value -> value.value.equals(role));
    }
}
```

I could define Predicates in the client class or directly pass as lambda expressions or method reference.(1)(2) Below, there are cases for them and I have noted which one is working or not.

```
public class UserService {

//...

public User getUserProfile() {
        //validateUser(Role.isInRealm());    -> OK
        validateUser(Role::isInRealm);       -> NOK
        validateUser(r -> Role.isInRealm()); -> NOK
        //validateUser(role -> Arrays.stream(Role.values()).anyMatch(value -> value.equals(role))); -> OK (1)
        //validateUser(s -> true); -> OK (2)
//...
}

private void validateUser(Predicate<String> predicate) {
        Authentication principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String role = utils.getRoles(principal).findFirst().get().getAuthority();
        if (!predicate.test(role)) {
            throw new ForbiddenAccessException(ResponseCode.FORBIDDEN_ACCESS.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I have a confusion about how to get a handle to a `Function` returning from a method.

While `isInRealm()` method returning a lambda expression as a Predicate, why I can't call it with `Role::isInRealm` or `r -> Role.isInRealm()`? When I try I get the error of `bad return type in lambda expression: Predicate<String> cannot be converted to boolean`.

When I pass the lambda expression directly in the client code it works, but in this case, I need to get the returning functional with `validateUser(Role.isInRealm())`. Why is it like that?

`Role.isInRealm()` makes sense since the method returns a function object we are getting the Object but since Java 8 stream API Functions are not first-class language constructs I can't fully grasp what is happening when getting it with `::`.

What is happening in the behind when we are getting with point or double colon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `validateUser` expectes a `Predicate<String>`, so method handles (the `::` syntax) and lambdas must conform to that functional interface.

For a method handle to conform to `Predicate<String>` there can be three possible method signatures (and return type) to match:

1. (non-static) `boolean methodName()` **in** the `String` class, referred to as `String::methodName`
2. (static) `boolean methodName(String value)` in any class referred to as `ClassName::methodName`
3. (non-static) `boolean methodName(String value)` in any class referred to as `someInstance::methodName`

`Role.isInRealm()` **returns** a predicate, so it cannot function as a predicate itself as it has `Predicate<String> methodName()` as its signature and return type. So `Role::isInRealm` cannot work.

Similarly `r -> Role.isInRealm()` will not work, because this is a lambda of the form `Function<String, Predicate<String>>` (or probably more correct: `Function<?, Predicate<String>>` as there is nothing to infer the type of `r`), not `Predicate<String>`

If you want to use `isInRealm` as a predicate itself, then you need to write it as:

```
public static boolean isInRealm(String role) {
     return Arrays.stream(values()).anyMatch(value -> value.value.equals(role));
}
```

Notice that instead of returning a lambda, it now returns a boolean result.

Then you can call it using:

```
validateUser(Role::isInRealm);
// notice how it passes r to isInRealm
validateUser(r -> Role.isInRealm(r));
```

Answer (score 3):

You're mixing lambda with invocation. In the following example `isInRealm` is invoked, and return value (lambda) is used:

```
validateUser(Role.isInRealm());
```

So effectively `role -> Arrays.stream(values()).anyMatch(value -> value.value.equals(role));` is passed to `validateUser` method.

In next two examples:

```
validateUser(Role::isInRealm);
validateUser(r -> Role.isInRealm());
```

you're trying to pass lambdas (suppliers), that **when invoked** will return the lambda you're looking for. You're not passing the `Predicate` to `validateUser`.

Answer (score 0):

method references are basically lambdas you need to pass something to the lambda in order for it to work, so your method need to **accept a parameter** and there needs to be a value it consumes
for example

```
(String s) -> System.out.println(s)
```

here the println method accepts a parameter and you are passing it a an actual value so you can use method reference here

```
System.out::println
```

but in your case i think it's better if you save the predicate in a variable instead of returning it from a method

```
public static Predicate<String> isInRealm = role -> Arrays.stream(values()).anyMatch(value -> value.name().equals(role));
```

then you can call validate method like this

```
validateUser(Role.isInRealm)
```